# Validation not accepting decimal numbers in field declared as decimal

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a razor view with textbox for updating database field. Field type is declared as decimal in model.

When i enter value like `5,25` i'm getting jquery validation error `"The field xxx must be a number."` When i enter it like `5.25`, jquery accept this value, but `ModelState.IsValid` in my Update controller become false and i'm getting error in modelstate.values[]... `"The value '5.25' is not valid for xxx.".`

I'm using

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

scripts on the view.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Looks like you have too many libraries.

Comment: In some locales the decimal character is ',' (comma) in others it's '.' (period).   You probably have the wrong locale set somewhere.

Comment: My system settings is ',' for decimal character, and mvc application is out of box. Did not mess with locales there...

Comment: It's probably not your system settings, but the browser settings...since that is where jquery runs.  You could try changing it:  http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Your-Browser%27s-Language

Comment: Not working... I added several different locales (including system default) and i still get jquery validation error...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the [jQuery.globalization](http://blog.jquery.com/2015/04/23/announcing-globalize-1-0/) library?
That solved locale issues for me. (There is also an older jQuery.globalize on Git Hub) 
The locale on the web server can also be different to the locale on the browser. Therefore the Browser accepts the 5.25 because the client locale is en-US, but the server is set to de (or similar) so the controller expects a 5,25 value. Never assume one locale, and use the Parsing functions with a locale specified.